# Painted over plastic material

Tags: materials, node-editor

Does anybody know how to make this kind of material, where there is a plastic base layer and looks like somebody painted over it? Including the displacement and everything?

The look I would like to achieve:
[image: The material I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: maybe it's more a question of topology than material? You need to keep your angles round

Comment: You could try with displacement

Answer (score 0):

You could *Bump* your *Normal* using *Noise* texture:

[image]

You could add smears by modifying (stretching) coordinates:

[image] Colored noise works nice here, because the effect changes abruptly when the normal changes.

Increase *Specular* and decrease *Roughness* for oil painting look.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this works very well for the paint layer. But I would also like a plastic layer under it. I did it with the mix shader node, but it looks weird at the intersections. Where the plastic and paint meet. This will be a closeup and I would really like to imitate the thickness of the paint. But I can't really figure out how to make the displacement be only on the paint and still look good. Can you help with that?